# from . import XXXX

Tags: python

In one of my Python packages the `__init__.py` file contains the statement

```
from . import XXXX
```

What does the "." mean here? I got this technique by looking at another package, but I don't understand what it means.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [relative import](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-relative-imports).

Comment: Duh, of course it is. Thanks for pointing me to the correct name of the feature.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 12):

Its a relative import.
From: http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement

> When specifying what module to import you do not have to specify the
>   absolute name of the module. When a module or package is contained
>   within another package it is possible to make a relative import within
>   the same top package without having to mention the package name. By
>   using leading dots in the specified module or package after from you
>   can specify how high to traverse up the current package hierarchy
>   without specifying exact names.
>
> One leading dot means the current
>   package where the module making the import exists. Two dots means up
>   one package level. Three dots is up two levels, etc. So if you execute
>   `from . import mod` from a module in the pkg package then you will end
>   up importing pkg.mod. If you execute from `..subpkg2 import mod` from
>   within pkg.subpkg1 you will import pkg.subpkg2.mod. The specification
>   for relative imports is contained within PEP 328.