# how is "from . import json" different from " import json"?

Tags: python

I am going through Flask source. I see a lot of statements like

```
from . import x
```

I am not Python novice so I understand what `from` and  `import` keywords do. But what is `from .` ? Could someone explain with an example?

Edit1:
My question is about just `import .` not `import .module`

Edit2:
how is `from . import x` different from from `import x`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python "from \[dot\]package import ..." syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511792/python-from-dotpackage-import-syntax)

Comment: Sort of a duplicate, but `from .` (just the dot, not something like `from .models`) appears different enough that it warrants its own question.

Comment: @Wright That question is about `.modulename`, not `.` by itself.

Comment: There's got to be a duplicate of this already, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [from . import XXXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417353/from-import-xxxx)

Comment: ``from .`` is a way of doing ``relative addressing``. More info at this link : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html?highlight=relative%20import#intra-package-references

Comment: @PW how is `from . import x` different from from `import x` ?

Comment: The ``.`` will force it to look for the module in the current package. For example, if you had a ``from . import json``, in your case it will import from flask's ``json`` module (flask.json) instead of the default python ``json`` module.

Comment: That clears my question. thanks @PW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from . import x`

Will import locally to that script.

Python includes a [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) library so

```
from . import json
```

Is used to avoid importing the [standard library `json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) and instead import a local python module

Answer (score 2):

It is an example of Intra-package references in python. (Check out section 6.4.2 on https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

When writing packages in python, `from . import X` is used to import sub-packages from the parent class, i.e. importing a sibling class. The `.` is only used to refer to the parent package in the relative path.

However, you can always import parent package without using the `.` in import statement, by using the name of the parent package name/path. Using `.` is just a handy shortcut.