# What does mean from . import?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7

Hello I am using Django with Python and I don't understand this :

```
from . import views
```

I would like to know what I am importing when I type that.

Thank you for your explanations

Comment: You import the `view.py` file in the same directory as the file where the `import` statement is located.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Describing it like that propagates the misconception that relative imports are about directories, when they're really about packages. There are very important differences; for example, if I have files `a.py` and `b.py` in the same directory and I run `python a.py`, `a.py` can't do `from . import b`, because `a.py` and `b.py` aren't submodules of a common package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [from . import XXXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417353/from-import-xxxx)

Answer (score 2):

You can import files, modules and packages using **relative** or **absolute** paths.

Take a look at this project:

```
-- project_folder
    --project_name
        ──settings.py
        ──init.py
        ──urls.py
        ──wsgi.py
    --app1
        ──__init__.py
        ── models.py
        ── views.py
        ── admin.py
        -- package1_folder
            ── hello_world.py
```

A **relative import** is used to retrieve a resource relative to the current path you are on.

So if you are currently working inside `app1 -> views.py` and you want to import `hello_world.py` to your views you can use `.` to specify a relative import to the current file you are working on.

So to import `hello_world.py` we could use `from .package1_folder import hello_world`.

If you just specify `from . import models` you are importing the models.py resource from the current folder you are on(app1).

An **absolute import** on the other hand is used to import a resource from anywhere in the project using the full path.

For example, you can use `from app1.package1_folder import hello_world` anywhere in your project and you will successfully import the file.

Answer (score 1):

You import views.py from the location of the python script that calls import statment.

Comment: No. If you write `import views`, you specify an "absolute path", so it is the `views.py` in the `PYTHON_PATH`, the `.` is a *relative path*.

Answer (score 1):

import from same directory ,
".." mean import from upper directory