# Why am i getting an error when i import a moduel

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, fastapi, uvicorn

Im following a postgresql tutorial and in the video he does

```
from . import models
```

then when i try it i can an error

i did exactly what he did in the video and i get this error

```
    from . import models
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

does anyone know why?

Comment: It's different in Python 3.6 vs previous python versions, so that may account for the difference.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The ImportError message is stating that Python expected a module to import `models` from, but didn't find it. Are you working from the same directory that the instructor is working from?

I'm not familiar with the tutorial, but given the import, it seems you're also learning Django. If so, are you sure you have Django installed?

As a general tip, in case you are indeed new to Stack Overflow, you may find it helpful to copy and paste the error message you're seeing, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22ImportError%3A%20attempted%20relative%20import%20with%20no%20known%20parent%20package%22).

You might find these questions' answers helpful as well:

- [What does mean from . import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55781711/what-does-mean-from-import/55782031#55782031)
- [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Comment: Im using fast api, and postgresql, they are in the same directory, the youtube video link is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sOvCWFmrtA&t=7225s and the time he does this is at 5:02:30